# Prefill Distribution manifest information during iOS app signing

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-signing

I sign my iOS app in XCode's archive manager for Ad-Hoc distribution for beta testers.

Every time I release a new beta version by pressing the `Distribute App` / `Ad Hoc` it asks for a `Distribution manifest information` with URLs to fill.

It's quite tedious to fill these fields every time, although these values don't change. Is it possible to pre-fill these fields by doing something in xcode project settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select Ad-Hoc distribution, simply uncheck the "Include manifest for over-the-air installation" option and you won't be prompted.

You can use a previously generated manifest for the new version unless you want to change something; The version number in the manifest is purely informational and doesn't need to match the version number in your app bundle.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I only re-generated the manifest because of the version number.

Answer (score 0):

I know you decided to just not include the manifest for over-the-air installation. In my case, though, I did want to automate this a bit. So, I used a third party tool, [TextExpander](https://textexpander.com), so that I can just type `otaqa` or `otaprod` and it will populate these three fields for me. I just included the three strings with tab keys in between them:

[image]

Note, I am unaffiliated with this paid app, TextExpander. But, I just found this workaround to be a great time-saver when needing to repeatedly enter the same three values in three separate text fields.

I really wish Xcode handled this process better, saving these values for us.